# How do I make a transfer in Dublin airport if my two flights are on separate tickets?

Tags: air-travel, transit, airports, dub

In the not too distant future I am travelling to Canada from the UK but it’s a lot cheaper to book separate flights to Dublin first, and then fly on to Canada (around £240).

Would I have to pick up my bags first then go on to check in again, or would my bags make it to the next flight if I leave a long enough gap between arriving and departing again?

Also, would I have to leave the arrival section to head to departures, or would I be able to check in at a desk in the arrivals area? I know that there are some airports that offer this facility.

Comment: A word of caution: if you book two separate tickets you are completely on your own if things go wrong. If your inbound flight to Dublin is late and you miss the connection, the second airline will simply cancel your trans-Atlantic flight and treat you as a “no show”. If you book everything on one ticket, the airline will deal with any missed connection.

Comment: Some credit cards have "insurance" for this.

Answer (score 12):

By default, you would have to collect your checked baggage and re-check it again. If you book your flights with airlines on the same alliance, you *may* have a chance to convince the check-in agent for your first leg to check your baggage through. It is not advisable to count on this, though.

Answer (score 8):

I have done this quite a few times but only with checking into a hotel in between. This way you are covered pretty well if something goes haywire.

With transatlantic flights from Europe, a well placed positioning flight on a low cost airline followed by a traditional airline flight the next day can save you an astonishing amount of money -- the tradeoff is of course time. If you want real madness: if you are in a very big hub city, say, London, it is often cheaper to fly to a smaller city, and then fly to the USA via London (!). Airlines make no sense.

Comment: "Airlines make no sense." -- or rather, airlines make too much sense. If people in smaller-city have less money than people in London, airlines are perfectly happy to segment the market, charge them lower prices, and independently make the decision that the best way to fly people from smaller-city to the US is via London :-) You might expect airlines to charge based solely on their costs, but they don't, they charge based on what the customer will pay. Not to mention taxes, subsidies and blah blah.

Comment: Many airports (esp. LHR) have rather expensive passenger fees and/or departure taxes. They do not charge transfer passengers on the grounds that it's often out of the passenger's control where they change. You avoid the fees by not beginning your trip there.